# Polynomial ring definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

Let $F$ be an arbitrary field (or just a ring). Usually $F[t]$ is defined as a set of all finite sequences of 'numbers' which can be multiplied etc, $F[t_1,t_2]$ is a ring of polynomials over $F[t_1]$ i.e the set of finite sequences of polynomials over $F$. Thus we can define $F[t_1,t_2,...t_n]$. The questions is how to define $F[T]$ if T is an arbitrary infinite set? 
Is it possible to define $F[T]$ a set of all finite formal linear combinations like $a_1t_1t_2...t_k+....$? (where $a_i\in F$, $t_i\in T$ and it can be met more than once) We also consider the case of uncountable $T$.

Comment: If anyone reads the previous one, he or she may think i understood what $Q[T]$ is. Here i ask it explicitly:), i mean here i want to understand how to build it correctly.

Comment: Please, read a bit further and you will see an answer, where Jack Schmidt told me what it is. Now i want to know how to build it, i understood what it is before.
I will take into account your wishes.